# Python 3: Importing Files / Modules from Scattered Directories and Files

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/pi
     - project/
          - p1v1.py
     - tools1/
          - __init__.py
          - tools1a/
               - __init__.py
               - file1.py
               - file2.py
               - tools1a1/
                    - __init__.py
                    - file3.py
                    - file4.py
               - tools1a2/
                    - __init__.py
                    - file5.py
                    - file6.py
```

I am trying to import all the modules from the `file1.py` into my project file `p1v1.py`

`from file1 import *`

but end up with either an

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

or an

`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

depending on what I use in `p1v1.py` because the functions in `file1.py` depend on `file3.py` and `file4.py`.  I would like to use explicit imports (for clarity), but I'm not sure how to do this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at that tutorial many times and couldn't understand how it worked / what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error eventually figured out how to solve this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'..')
from tools1.tools1a.file1 import function as f1
```

Note: For this to work, I needed to be editing and executing my script `p1v1.py` out of the working directory `/home/pi/project/`. Hope this helps others with a similar problem!